# iPhone release build memory error

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcodebuild

I get this error when I try to build a release version of my app. It throws an error for a single file that is fairly large, but nowhere near 400+MB (in the KBs)

```
Out of memory allocating 455627472 bytes after a total of 0 bytes
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/developerusr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I have 3GB of free ram (out of 6GB), plenty of CPU power and 50GB free on my hard drive. What could be causing this issue?

Some additional information I found about the error:

Here is some more info i found about the error:

```
cc1obj(19764) malloc: *** mmap(size=455630848) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

cc1obj: out of memory allocating 455627472 bytes after a total of 0 bytes
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_objc_msgSendSuper2$stub
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_objc_msgSend$stub
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_SUP_REFS_$_0
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_26
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_23
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_25
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_2
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_19
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_16
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_15
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_20
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_5
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_2
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_21
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_24
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_22
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_11
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_4
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_12
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_13
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_14
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_18
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_17
{standard input}:unknown:Undefined local symbol L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_10
Command /Developer3.1Final/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is during the actual build process, then my guess is your Mac needs a reboot or a reinstall of Xcode. You'd never need that amount of RAM for compiling, so it's going recursive or similar. I'd doubt you could code something to cause that unless there was something wrong with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

NM, didn't see it was cc2obj that died.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this,   it is not an actual memory error...

what is happening is that you have your Xcode target Build settings of either release or debug and the particular setting of "optimization level"  set to Fast, or faster, or fastest..

there appears to be a bug in there somewhere,   set it to none,  or try the Os, or O3 (i don't think fastest is effected)..

this will very likely solve someones problem that comes across this thread.  for sure try "none" first...  this will confirm that this is what is happening in someone's case that sees this...

i can tell that McPragma is having this problem for sure,  because he/she describes changing from debug to release, and this causes it (debug is already set to none) and release is set to something else...  when that is the case... for sure it is that particular build setting...